# How can I get my passport from the Brazilian consulate in Los Angeles after it issues my visa?

Tags: us-citizens, brazil, tourist-visas, application-status

I live in Utah and must fly to Los Angeles to get my Brazilian visa. I read this [on their site](http://losangeles.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/important_information.xml):

> Plan your visa application in advance, as it takes the Consulate at least 5 business days to issue a visa (the processing time does not include Saturdays, Sundays and [Holidays](http://losangeles.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/hours_and_holidays.xml) and only after presenting in person your visa application, the processing time will start counting).

With the return flight and accommodations in mind, does this mean I have to stay in LA up to 5 days before I receive my actual visa stamp in my passport?

Comment: surely they'd mail it to you once it's done?

Comment: Have you checked with visa service providers, they might be more economical?  Travisa website indicates that if there is time and your documents are OK you may not have to physically appear, they can process it for you.  Also I know the Miami consulate will send the passport back by courier (FedEx, UPS, etc) if you provide a self-addressed, prepaid shipping label.

Comment: When I got my visa 2 years ago (in Houston), they gave it to me in about 5 minutes. Perhaps they've changed procedures, or different consulates do it differently.

Comment: You should confirm with them directly. Call them. They might be required to give you your visa within five days (or tell you why you won't get one), but in practice, they might do it on the same day, if you present yourself in person.

Comment: @Christian so what happened?

Answer (score 6):

Unlike some other Brazilian consulates in the US, the Los Angeles consulate *will not* mail your passport back to you after processing.

> The Consulate cannot be held responsible for mailed passports or visa applications and will not mail applications or visas back.

Your [options](http://losangeles.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/important_information.xml) are to either pick it up yourself, or to have someone pick it up on your behalf and send it to you.

> The consular agent will tell you the date and time your passport will be returned and will hand you a receipt. On the specified date, anyone can pick up the passport(s) on your behalf, provided that he or she have the original receipt.

On having someone pick it up: You can also have your application submitted by a [visa agency](http://losangeles.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/approved_visa_agencies.xml) on the approved list. If you use one of these agencies, you do not need to go to the consulate at all, and they will handle everything for you, including returning your passport. You should allow 12 business days (and possibly more) if you use a visa agency.